# Sorting list using bubble algorithm method Unity C# dont work

Tags: c#, list, sorting, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to sort a list of object in unity by a property value (EnemyDificultyLevel) using the bubble algorithm method, but something is wrong with it and I cant figure out what it is.
One value always end up being misplaced.

```
for (int i =0; i< auxenemyPrefabs.Length; i++)
    {


        float val1 = auxenemyPrefabs[i].GetComponent<EnemyDifficultyAlgorithm_DCH>().EnemyDificultyLevel;


        for (int j = auxenemyPrefabs.Length-1; j >0; j--)

        {




            float val2 = auxenemyPrefabs[j].GetComponent<EnemyDifficultyAlgorithm_DCH>().EnemyDificultyLevel;


            if (val1 > val2)
            {
                GameObject aux = auxenemyPrefabs[i];
                auxenemyPrefabs[i] = auxenemyPrefabs[j];
                auxenemyPrefabs[j] = aux;

            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Could you show what you get at the end ?

Comment: By the way, what you do here is not the bubble sorting algorithm

Comment: In your for loop, it should be j>=0. That is your problem

Comment: As somebody said this is not a bubble sort. In bubble sort comparison is done between adjacent objects. I would use Linq. auxenemyPrefabs. = auxenemyPrefabs.OrderBy(prefab => prefab.GetComponent<EnemyDifficultyAlgorithm_DCH>().EnemyDificultyLevel).ToArray()

Comment: What?  Is this a class project to display the knowledge you've learned over the semester, Otherwise, Why would you be implementing your own sorting algorithm?

Comment: Hi, tks for the comments, Its a class project indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 things:

1. You are swapping elements from the already sorted portion of the array (`j > 0` should be `j > i`)
2. You are updating `auxenemyPrefabs[i]` in the second loop but you are not updating `val1` which should correspond to the current value of `auxenemyPrefabs[i]`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < auxenemyPrefabs.Length - 1; i++)
{
    float val1 = auxenemyPrefabs[i].GetComponent<EnemyDifficultyAlgorithm_DCH>().EnemyDificultyLevel;

    // j<=i is already sorted
    for (int j = auxenemyPrefabs.Length - 1; j > i; j--)
    {
        float val2 = auxenemyPrefabs[j].GetComponent<EnemyDifficultyAlgorithm_DCH>().EnemyDificultyLevel;
        if (val1 > val2)
        {
            GameObject aux = auxenemyPrefabs[i];
            auxenemyPrefabs[i] = auxenemyPrefabs[j];
            auxenemyPrefabs[j] = aux;

            val1 = val2;
        }
    }
}
```

And as mentioned in one of the comments this is not Bubble Sort, this is Selection Sort.
 You can get rid of some unnecessary swaps by just remembering the minimum index in the inner loop and swapping the elements at the end:

```
for (int i = 0; i < auxenemyPrefabs.Length - 1; i++)
{
    float val1 = auxenemyPrefabs[i].GetComponent<EnemyDifficultyAlgorithm_DCH>().EnemyDificultyLevel;
    int minindx = i;

    // j<=i is already sorted
    for (int j = auxenemyPrefabs.Length - 1; j > i; j--)
    {
        float val2 = auxenemyPrefabs[j].GetComponent<EnemyDifficultyAlgorithm_DCH>().EnemyDificultyLevel;
        if (val1 > val2)
        {
            minindx = j;                
            val1 = val2;
        }
    }
    GameObject aux = auxenemyPrefabs[i];
    auxenemyPrefabs[i] = auxenemyPrefabs[minindx];
    auxenemyPrefabs[minindx] = aux;
}
```

But this is probably not the best idea overall especially if you have a big list of prefabs. In the inner loop calls `GetComponent` n times for the same prefab.

Comment: Tks for the answer, I will try this as soon as I get home. Also seems like I misunderstood the definition of the bubble sort, tks a lot for the clarification!